# Why does this animation finish choppy?

Tags: html, css, animation

Trying to do a fairly simple list animation that grows when you mouseover.

http://jsfiddle.net/cvpehzb7/

The animation finishes choppily and goes out way too far.

Maybe my padding is the problem.
I tried using width, but I got similar results.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div id = "user-task-bar">

                <ol class="task-list">

                    <li> <span> My Products </span> </li>
                    <li> My Profile </li>
                    <li> Get Support </li>


                </ol>
            </div>

#user-task-bar {

position: absolute;

left:30px;
width:240px;

}

#user-task-bar ol.task-list  {

padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
width:100%;
list-style:none;

}


#user-task-bar .task-list li {
width:100%; 
padding: 0px;
font-size: 14px;

border-top: 1px solid #000; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
border-right: 2px solid #000;

border-left: 2px solid #000;

text-align:center;
 padding: 15% 0px;
 background: #f2f3f2;
}

#user-task-bar .task-list li:hover {

 -webkit-animation: grow-right 300ms;
 animation: grow-right 300ms; 
 animation-timing-function: ease-out;

 padding: 15% 8%;
 cursor:pointer;
 background: #fff;

}

@-webkit-keyframes grow-right {

    0% { padding: 15% 0; }
    100% { padding: 15% 3px; }
}

@keyframes grow-right{

    0% { padding: 15% 0; }
    100% { padding: 15% 3px; }
}

#user-task-bar .task-list li :last {
border:  0px;
}

#user-task-bar .task-list li  span{ 

   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the animation is done, the original value of your padding is re-applied.

You can use `animation-fill-mode:  forwards`, to keep the properties of the last keyframe. See https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

But a simpler way, and wide supported, is to set the value of the properties in the last keyframe equal to the default values.

Examples:

- with animation-fill-mode: http://jsfiddle.net/cvpehzb7/5/
- with the same value of padding in last keyframe and in the hover rule: http://jsfiddle.net/cvpehzb7/3/
- with a CSS transition: http://jsfiddle.net/cvpehzb7/10/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `keyframes` with a final state, the desired attributes should also be set correctly.

In this section, padding on hover should also give those 3px:

```
#user-task-bar .task-list li:hover {

  -webkit-animation: grow-right 300ms;
  animation: grow-right 300ms; 
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;

  padding: 15% 3px;
            // ^^^
  cursor:pointer;
  background: #fff;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvpehzb7/8/)

Then you'll need the reverse animation, too.

What about using [css transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) in this case instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id = "user-task-bar">
    <ol class="task-list">
        <li> <span> My Products </span> </li>
        <li> My Profile </li>
        <li> Get Support </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#user-task-bar {

position: absolute;


left:30px;
width:240px;


}

#user-task-bar ol.task-list  {

    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;

}

#user-task-bar .task-list li {
    width:100%; 
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;

    border-top: 1px solid #000; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
    border-right: 2px solid #000;

    border-left: 2px solid #000;

    text-align:center;
    padding: 15% 0px;
    background: #f2f3f2;
}

#user-task-bar .task-list li:hover {
    -webkit-transition: padding 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: padding 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: padding 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: padding 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: padding 1s ease-out;
    padding: 15% 8%;
    cursor:pointer;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Tried it and it works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is in padding. You need to use smaller one.

```
#user-task-bar .task-list li:hover {
 -webkit-animation: grow-right 300ms;
 animation: grow-right 300ms; 
 animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  padding: 15% 2%;
 cursor:pointer;
 background: #fff;

}
```